# How to delete the rows which are not updated?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
 Id | value  
 --------
  1 |  bla bla bla
  2 |  bla bla
```

my application receives:

1. rows with ids to update
2. new data without ids to insert
3. if an id doesn't exist I should delete it from the table

for example, when this data is received:

```
[
{"Id"=>1 ,"value"=>" value 1 "},
{"Id"=>"","value"=>"value2"}
]
```

after running the query, the table should contain these rows:

```
Id | value  
------------
 1 | value1     , update row
 2 | bla bla    , this row will be deleted row because I don't receive the id
 3 | value 2    , there is a new row, because I got an empty Id
```

How can I implement this query?

Comment: isn't it easier to drop data in the table and just insert/update new that you have coming?

Comment: that mean I should run tow queries , right ? but I am searching for more professional way !

Comment: Nothing unprofessional about two queries

Comment: it is not very professional to use database as temporary file. And by the way you are planninig to use 2 queries : one to update, and another to insert? aren't you?

Comment: @Alex temporary file, am I using the database as temporary file ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you add a TimeStamp column, update that column as a part of your INSERT and UPDATE code.  At that point, you could run an additional query to DELETE rows that are "old" based on the TimeStamp column.